# Calculating linear velocity based on the (Euler) rotation matrix having 2 time indices

Tags: differential-geometry, velocity, angular-velocity

Normally, we denote a rotation matrix with respect to time as $R(t)$. As I understand, we can only denote like that because the initial observation is assumed to be zero ($t_0 = 0$) and $t$ is actually the delayed duration from that initial observation.

However, I am dealing with $t_0 \ne 0$? A common sense would be to denote the rotation matrix as $R(t, t+\tau)$ to show rotation has been done from the initial observation $t$ to the current observation $t + \tau$ and that
$$R(0, t) = R(t) \\ R(t, t+\tau) \ne R(t+\tau) - R(t)$$

Then, the motion/displacement of a point from $t$ to $t+\tau$ would be
$$ 
p(t+\tau) = R(t, t+\tau) p(t),
$$
and the linear velocity of this point, defined as the displacement within a infinitesimal duration, would be
$$
v(t) = \lim\limits_{\tau \to 0} \quad \frac{p(t+\tau) - p(t)}{\tau} \\
= \lim\limits_{\tau \to 0} \quad \frac{R(t, t+\tau) p(t) - p(t)}{\tau} \\
= \lim\limits_{\tau \to 0} \quad \frac{R(t, t+\tau) - I}{\tau} p(t)
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix. This is a $0/0$ type of limit since $R(t, t) = I$ (i.e., no rotation), thus $R(t, t+\tau) - I \to 0$ as $\tau \to 0$.

I know what $\frac{dR(t)}{dt} = \Omega(t)R(t)$, where $\Omega(t)$ is skew-symmetric. This formula is shown in this book: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-75277-8.

Currently, I'm clueless what to do next as I've never encountered such a problem before and the equation seems no help.

My question is, is my approach to determine $v(t)$ based on rotation matrix correct? How can I determine $v(t)$ in closed form (no limit, no derivative)?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hi Valter, I just added the question, dunno why it got left out after posting...

Comment: Well, the limit you wrote (a derivative) just produces that matrix $\Omega(t)$… No chances to find a closed form without referring to that derivative…

Comment: Yes, that first limit is the definition of derivative. But I couldn't see why the third one is. Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct and your perspective  is nothing more than a change of notation with respect to the one adopted in the book.

Taking the formalism in the book into account, your third limit can be computed obtaining
$$v(t) =\lim_{\tau \to 0}  \frac{R(t, t+\tau) - I}{\tau} p(t) = \Omega(t) p(t)\:.$$
Let us prove it.

Comparing your notation with the one used in the book,
$$R(t, t’)p(t) = R(t’)p(0)= R(t’)R(t)^{-1}p(t).$$
Since $p(t)$ can be chosen arbitrarily, we conclude that
$$R(t, t’) = R(t’)R(t)^{-1}.$$
This is the central identity where the interplay of your point of view and the one adopted in the book shows up.

Now let us pass to your limit by taking advantage of this identity.
$$\lim_{\tau \to 0}  \frac{R(t, t+\tau) - I}{\tau} p(t)
= \lim_{\tau \to 0}  \frac{R(t+\tau)R(t)^{-1} - I}{\tau}p(t) = \lim_{\tau \to 0}  \frac{R(t+\tau)R(t)^{-1} - R(t)R(t)^{-1}}{\tau}p(t)$$
$$=\lim_{\tau \to 0}  \frac{R(t+\tau) - R(t)}{\tau}R(t)^{-1}p(t)= \frac{dR(t)}{dt}R(t)^{-1}p(t) = \Omega(t) p(t)\:.$$
Above, I used the fact that $$\frac{dR(t)}{dt} =\Omega(t)R(t)$$
is equivalent to
$$\Omega(t) = \frac{dR(t)}{dt}R(t)^{-1}$$
which can also be considered the **definition** of the matrix $\Omega(t)$.

This definition also proves that $\Omega(t)$ is skew-symmetric. To demonstrate  it,  let us start from the fact that $R(t)^{-1} = R(t)^t$, so that
$$R(t)R(t)^t =I\:.$$
Taking the $t$-derivative of both sides
$$ \frac{dR(t)}{dt}R(t)^{t}+  R(t)\frac{dR(t)^t}{dt}=0\:,\tag{1}$$
namely
$$ \Omega(t)+ \Omega(t)^t=0\:,\tag{2}$$
that is
$$ -\Omega(t)=  \Omega(t)^t\:.$$
To get (2) out of (1), I used
$$R(t)\frac{dR(t)^{t}}{dt} = \left(\frac{dR(t)}{dt} R(t)^{t}\right)^t=  \left(\frac{dR(t)}{dt} R(t)^{-1}\right)^t= \Omega(t)^t\:.$$

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. It's so good.

Comment: you're welcome. If you are satisfied with my answer please accept it.